# jquery mobile not working with google app script

Tags: jquery-mobile, google-apps-script

When I've linked jQuery Mobile in my HTML Frontend in Google App Script, the following error will pop up in chrome debug tool.

Could not create the property 'jQuery110204039543210528791': USELESS is not extensible. 702029031-maestro_htmlapp_bin_maestro_htmlapp.js?lib=MT0FjXL5Y7sJYLE797XdNlumjcy0VxvZE:62
jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js:2: Could not create the property 'jQuery110204039543210528791': USELESS is not extensible.

More looks likely the Caja in Google App Script is not supporting jQuery Mobile?

Any idears?

Answer (score 1):

Caja sanitation prevents jQuery mobile markup. This is an issue addressed in the [Issue Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1665).

I'm not sure how long it would take to have jQuery added to Caja's list...